# How to change Word's document language including captions "Figure" and "Table"?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am starting a document in English on a French computer and my captions are set to "Figure" and "Tableau". I would like to change this to the document language.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create and use custom labels for your captions.

*Note, those custom labels will not travel with the document. That is, if opened on a different computer with Office set to be French, the Custom labels would need to be added if new captions were to be added. Those already in the document will not be changed, though.*

Comment: So what is the solution if I want to write a document in different languages

Comment: Add the custom labels as you need them. They will remain in your list for that document.